# Text semantic similarity by analogy in the hypernym level using Python

Tags: python, text, nlp, semantics, similarity

I have a few long (50-lines) paragraphs which I would like to measure their similarity using Python. I am more interested in the semantic similarity of these texts in the hypernym (a term in linguistic) level with the focus on functions and processes. To further clarify, I would call two pieces of text similar if both referring to the same function or process, regardless of the words used in them.

Here are two examples:
Similar_Sentences = ("use a tube to suck soda in","transfer blood to the heart using a pump and artery").
Unsimilar_Sentences = ("use a tube to suck soda in","do some programming to get better").

In the first example, "tube" ~ "artery", "soda" ~ "blood", and "suck in" ~ "transfer to". I hope it is clear what I am interested in.

Based on my research on NLP algorithms and tools, NLTK and WordNet in Python seem the right tools for this task, but I am not sure how.

Referring to any relevant tutorial or source for learning, as well as any suggestions is appreciated in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is [a great post on NLPForHackers](https://nlpforhackers.io/wordnet-sentence-similarity/) describing how to implement sentence similarity using wordnet.

Their ingredients:

1. A POS tagger to narrow down the list of synsets for each word (after this, the authors just take the first synset)
2. [path_similarity](https://www.nltk.org/howto/wordnet.html): a metric showing how far two words are from each other on the taxonomy graph
3. Aggregation of word-level similarities: max, then average.

This already works pretty well: for your positive example, the similarity score is 0.29, and for the negative example, the score is only 0.20.

I would suggest a few improvements:

1. Use not only the first found synset, but max over all synsets for a word. It makes the scores for your positive and negative examples 0.36 and 0.23 - farther from each other than before
2. Use word mover distance to aggregate word similarities, instead of max-and-mean. I convert between similarity and distance by formula `s=1-d^2/2`. This pushes scores for your positive and negative samples even further apart - to 0.41 and 0.19 respectively.

Here is the code for my final version:

```
from nltk import word_tokenize, pos_tag
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
import numpy as np
from pyemd import emd

import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')
nltk.download('averaged_perceptron_tagger')
nltk.download('wordnet')

def penn_to_wn(tag):
    """ Convert between a Penn Treebank tag to a simplified Wordnet tag """
    if tag.startswith('N'):
        return 'n'
    if tag.startswith('V'):
        return 'v'
    if tag.startswith('J'):
        return 'a'
    if tag.startswith('R'):
        return 'r'
    return None

def tagged_to_synsets(word, tag):
    wn_tag = penn_to_wn(tag)
    if wn_tag is None:
        return []
    return wn.synsets(word, wn_tag)

def get_counts(sentence, vocab):
    weights = np.zeros(len(vocab))
    for w in sentence:
        if w not in vocab:
            continue
        weights[vocab.index(w)] += 1
    return weights / sum(weights)

def sim3(sentence1, sentence2):
    sentence1 = pos_tag(word_tokenize(sentence1))
    sentence2 = pos_tag(word_tokenize(sentence2))
    vocab = [pair for pair in sorted(set(sentence1).union(set(sentence2))) if penn_to_wn(pair[1])]

    w1 = get_counts(sentence1, vocab)
    w2 = get_counts(sentence2, vocab)

    synsets = [tagged_to_synsets(*tagged_word) for tagged_word in vocab]

    similarities = np.array([[
        max([s1.path_similarity(s2) or 0 for s1 in w1 for s2 in w2], default=0)
        for w2 in synsets] for w1 in synsets]
    )
    distances = np.sqrt(2*(1-similarities))
    distance = emd(w1, w2, distances)
    similarity = 1 - distance**2 / 2
    return similarity

print(sim3("use a tube to suck soda in","transfer blood to the heart using a pump and artery"))
print(sim3("use a tube to suck soda in","do some programming to get better"))
# 0.41046117311104957
# 0.19280421873943732
```

We can try to evaluate this similarity method on a dataset - e.g. on Quora Question Pairs

```
import pandas as pd
from tqdm.auto import tqdm, trange
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('http://qim.fs.quoracdn.net/quora_duplicate_questions.tsv', sep='\t')
sample = df.sample(1000, random_state=1)
sims = pd.Series([sim3(sample.iloc[i].question1, sample.iloc[i].question2) for i in trange(sample.shape[0])], index=sample.index)

# produce a plot
sims[sample.is_duplicate==0].hist(density=True);
sims[sample.is_duplicate==1].hist(alpha=0.5, density=True);
plt.legend(['non-duplicates', 'duplicates'])
plt.title('distribution of wordnet-sentence-similarity\n on quora question pairs');
```

You can see from the image that scores for duplicate pairs are on average much higher than for non-duplicates, but the overlap is still huge.

[image]

If you want a quantitative metric, you can evaluate e.g. ROC AUC. On this dataset, it is 70%, which is far from perfect but makes a decent baseline.

```
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score
print(roc_auc_score(sample.is_duplicate, sims))
# 0.7075210210273749
```

Comment: Thanks, @DavidDale for your comments and code. It seems to be a good start. Any other algorithm or similarity metrics that could result in a larger difference between similar and unsimilar sentences?

Comment: Maybe, this one metric is already good enough. 
But to be sure, we should test it on your own dataset, or choose one of existing semantic  text similarity datasets e.g. from here https://github.com/brmson/dataset-sts

Comment: I have updated my answer to include numeric evaluation

Comment: Thanks, David, I will give it a try with my dataset, as well as the other datasets you suggested. Hope it gives the resolution I need. Fingers crossed.